# Access OAuth2 endpoint from an ASP.NET Core Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API application, and this web API needs to call another 3rd-party API which is authenticated using OAuth2. It is required to invoke the `/token` endpoint of this 3rd-party API by passing client_id and client_secret, and the grant type is client_credentials. And then make a subsequent request using the bearer token received to retrieve data from the 3rd-party API .

Based on my research this requirement can be implemented using `HttpClient`, and call 3rd-party API from the .NET Core Web API controller (or ideally in a service class accessed by the controller).

My question is is there another way/better approach to achieve this requirement? One concern I have  in above approach is it will call the 3rd-party `/token` endpoint for each request. Is it possible to do some implementation in `Startup.cs` class?

Comment: I recommends read this article [Which OAuth2 0 flow should I use](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use) first.

After you choose the most appropriate flow for your needs, you could create a class `ThirdPartyClient` that extends from `HttpClient` and append the logic for the authentication flow you choose.

With this, you would have a client to consume the 3rd-party API that you could inject wherever you need.

NOTE: In the Startup.cs only use it to configure the DI and necessary services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/overview.html). It provides extension methods for `HttpClient` to handle `client_credentials` (and other) OAuth flow, caches the token (until it expires), so you don't hammer `/token` endpoint at every request and refreshes the token when needed.

[image]

You need to configure it in your `Startup` class, or implement `ITokenClientConfigurationService` if you need configure `HttpClient`s dynamically.

```cs
services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
{
    options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
        ClientId = "m2m.short",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
        Scope = "api" // optional
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @abdusco. If we do this, will the 1st token be retrieved when the application starts, or will it be retrieved on demand only, when it is actually required to call the 3rd-party api?

Comment: It's fetches tokens on-demand. You could attach a `IHostedService` and prefetch a token if that's important.

Comment: I was able to access the API using this. But when I expand the httpClient instance return from HttpClientFactory, the Authorization header is null. I expected the bearer token to be available in Authorization header. So how this is working, where is the token set in the header?

Comment: It's adding a `DelegatingHandler` to `HttpClient`s which works like a middleware. It intercepts the request you send, adds / inspects the response to see if it needs to refresh the token https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore/blob/27e966bf6729530e4a7480478f18302fe996a7f6/src/AccessTokenManagement/ClientAccessToken/ClientAccessTokenHandler.cs#L31-L46

Comment: Is there a way to use this altogether with an username and password? I need to provide that also for the auth request.